# Minicom Null Character

Tags: unix, terminal, serial-port

I am trying to read out data from serial port using Minicom.
I think so that when my program write a character with value 0, the minicom omits the data somehow. I don't see 0 or NULL character in the output. I don't know how to resolve this problem.

Thanks,
Pranav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to avoid this situation, I just implemented the XModem Protocol on my device and used the Minicom Xmodem Receive File to receive the entire data along with the null characters.

The xmodem code can be found here - 
http://www.codeforge.com/article/21174